# OAuth Request Token Error:401 in flickr

Tags: javascript, angularjs, oauth, flickr

I'm developing a mobile application for uploading pictures to flickr. But I can't even do the first step ie.,request token successfully. I signed the the base url and added the signature parameter to the code. I used the `http://oauth.googlecode.com/svn/code/javascript/oauth.js` and `http://oauth.googlecode.com/svn/code/javascript/sha1.js` libraries in this other than AngularJS.
Sent the GET request as follows.

```
$scope.test=function(){
        var preURL="http://www.flickr.com/services/oauth/request_token";
        var accessor = {
            consumerSecret: "a3439ab5915a03e4c", 
            tokenSecret   : ""
        };
        var message = {
            method: "GET", 
            action: preURL, 
            parameters: OAuth.decodeForm("oauth_callback=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.flickr.com")
        };
        message.parameters.push(["oauth_version", "1.0"]);
        message.parameters.push(["oauth_consumer_key", "1cfb4bb9b0e0bec71554e66da9da4582"]);
        message.parameters.push(["oauth_timestamp", OAuth.timestamp()]);
        message.parameters.push(["oauth_nonce", OAuth.nonce(11)]);
        message.parameters.push(["oauth_signature_method", "HMAC-SHA1"]);


        OAuth.SignatureMethod.sign(message, accessor);
        console.log("signatureBaseString" + OAuth.SignatureMethod.getBaseString(message));
        console.log("signature"           + OAuth.getParameter(message.parameters, "oauth_signature"));
        var requestTokenURL=OAuth.addToURL(preURL,message.parameters);
        console.log(requestTokenURL);
        $http({
            method: message.method, 
            url: requestTokenURL
        }).
        success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
            console.log("success");
            }).
        error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
           console.log("error");
            });
    }
```

An error is occuring with the following Network status:

```
    GET http://www.flickr.com/services/oauth/request_tok...1&oauth_signature=h0pdL6ZzYqGnGsrHbqjwFCIGg2Y%3D 
401 Unauthorized
```

I logged the following parameters in console.

**signatureBaseString:**

```
GET&http%3A%2F%2Fwww.flickr.com%2Fservices%2Foauth%2Frequest_token&oauth_callback%3Dhttp%253A%252F%252Fwww.google.com%26oauth_consumer_key%3D1cfb4bb9b0e0bec71554e66da9da4582%26oauth_nonce%3DzKxKd3VJxEB%26oauth_signature_method%3DHMAC-SHA1%26oauth_timestamp%3D1389180736%26oauth_version%3D1.0
```

**Signature**

```
h0pdL6ZzYqGnGsrHbqjwFCIGg2Y=
```

**RequestTokenURL**

```
    http://www.flickr.com/services/oauth/request_token?oauth_callback=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.google.com&oauth_version=1.0&oauth_consumer_key=1cfb4bb9b0e0bec71554e66da9da4582&oauth_timestamp=1389180736&oauth_nonce=zKxKd3VJxEB&oauth_signature_method=HMAC-SHA1&oauth_signature=h0pdL6ZzYqGnGsrHbqjwFCIGg2Y%3D
```

I entered the RequestTokenURL in browser and got this result:

```
oauth_problem=signature_invalid&debug_sbs=GET&http%3A%2F%2Fwww.flickr.com%2Fservices%2Foauth%2Frequest_token&oauth_callback%3Dhttp%253A%252F%252Fwww.google.com%26oauth_consumer_key%3D1cfb4bb9b0e0bec71554e66da9da4582%26oauth_nonce%3D6XctoZTWmaH%26oauth_signature_method%3DHMAC-SHA1%26oauth_timestamp%3D1389181211%26oauth_version%3D1.0
```

Comment: I used the callback url as flicker.com itself. Is there any problem with that?

Comment: I got the answer. I will post it as answer in a day or two. Please comment if anyone need urgent help. The answer in short. my consumer secret was wrong. Another thing is that it's not possible to do the request token process in a client side script.

Comment: When were you going to post your answer?

Comment: Sorry, I forgot the solution to this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This javascript library might help you on OAuth's stuff: [oauth-1.0a](https://github.com/ddo/oauth-1.0a)

It support both client side and node.js

Cheers

Comment: It looks promising. I will definitely give it a try when working with OAuth 1.0a.